# Avoid excluding similar lines while parsing a specific txt file to csv

Tags: php, csv, parsing

I need to parse a plain text file *into* a csv file (plain text format too). So I have a php script working on a server with PHP Version 5.3.13. And there is no way to upgrage. It works fine kinda...

First. Here is the php script: (*it is the full working script*)

```
<?php
// INPUT RAW FILE -- UTF8 !!!!
$data = trim(file_get_contents('inbox_file_utf8_clean.txt'));

$all_lines = preg_split("/\r?\n/", $data);
$date_id_line = array_shift($all_lines);
if(!preg_match('/^\d+\s\w+\s(?<time>\d+:\d+)\sId:\s(?<id>\d+).*/', $date_id_line, $matches)) {
  trigger_error('Failed to match ID and timestamp', E_USER_ERROR);
}
$output_data = array(
  'info' => array(
    'id' => $matches['id'],
    'time' => $matches['time']
  ),
  'data' => array()
);

$all_text_headers = array_values(preg_grep('/^\s*\(/', $all_lines));

// The first "Text header" is a parent.
// Count the number of leading whitespaces to determine other parents
preg_match('/^\x20*/', $all_text_headers[0], $leading_space_matches);
$leading_spaces = $leading_space_matches[0];
$num_leading_spaces = strlen($leading_spaces);
$parent_lead = str_repeat(' ', $num_leading_spaces) . '(';
$parent = NULL;
foreach($all_text_headers as $index => $header_line) {
  list($lead, $item_value) = explode(') ', $header_line);
  list($topic, $topic_count) = array_map('trim',
    preg_split('/\s{2,}/', $item_value, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
  );

  $topic_count = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $topic_count);

  if($is_parent = ($parent === NULL || strpos($lead, $parent_lead) === 0)) {
    $parent = $topic;
  }

  if($is_parent) {
    $output_data['data'][$parent] = array(
      'count' => $topic_count,
      'values' => array(),
    );
  } else {
    $output_data['data'][$parent]['values'][] = array(
      'topic' => $topic,
      'count' => $topic_count
    );
  }
}

$csv_delimiter = ';';
//output file -- result file -- CSV -- 
$handle = fopen('csv.txt', 'wb');

fputcsv($handle, array_values($output_data['info']), $csv_delimiter);

foreach($output_data['data'] as $parent_topic => $data) {
  $child_data = array();
  if($data['values']) {
    foreach($data['values'] as $arr) {
      $child_data[] = sprintf('%s x%d', $arr['topic'], $arr['count']);
    }
  }
  fputcsv($handle, array(
    $parent_topic,
    $data['count'],
    implode(', ', $child_data)
  ), $csv_delimiter);
}

fclose($handle);

echo "it's kinda done :-)";

$order_num = $matches['id'];

sleep(4);
?>
```

The file I need to parse looks like this: (*that example is the real plain text file that I have to parse. It is just a plain text file in utf8 encoding. It is real 'input' text file.*)

```
18 jun 15:28 Id: 42 #1 Random Text                                     
(Text header 1) Apple                    15
   (Text header 1) Really long line           
   here is the rest of the             
   long line that does'n get parsed
(Text header 1) Milk          2
(Text header 1) Ice cream                   4
(Text header 1) Ice cream                   4
(Text header 1) Pencil            1
(Text header 1) Box                    1
   (Text header 1) Cardboard                 x1
   (Text header 1) White                 x1
   (Text header 1) Cube              x1
(Text header 1) Phone     1
   (Text header 1) Specific text                x1
   (Text header 1) Symbian                x1
```

The format descriptin is: *just a plain text file. First line is the header. All the rest lines (exept the lines starts with spaces) are 'index' lines. All the lines starting with leading spaces are 'child' lines*.

And I get the output result csv file: (*that expample is a real plain text output.*)

```
42;15:28
Apple;15;Really long line;
Milk;2;
"Ice cream";4;
Pencil;1;
Box;1;"Cardboard x1, White x1, Cube x1";
Phone;1;"Specific text x1, Symbian x1";
```

I've one *problem* there.

*If* the input file contains **two similar lines**, the out put csv file contains **only one** of those two lines. I need them both.

So in the example input file I've got two '**Ice cream**'.
But the output contains only one '**Ice cream**'.
How can I make them get parsed both?

Please, help...

Comment: The first question that needs answering is: What is the format of the text file? Given the example, and your code, we can guess, but it is better to be sure.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the second code block

Comment: @Andreas That's not code, it's text, and it's only an example, not a format description. It could tell use what charachters are present/permitted where. It could also tell us what the optional thingy at the end is, that indention seems to mean someting, etc.

Comment: All the php code (script) is full working code that is parsing the input file (and it's just a plain text in utf8 encoding) and the output file is just a text file (and it's kinda csv file format). Now is it more clear? Thank you for asking.

Comment: The php script is... just a text file. The input file is just a plain text file in utf8 encoding. The output text file is just a plain text file... All the code and examples are the real epamples. What you see in my question blocks are real and represent real code and files... What you see is what I have.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: I've updated my question again... Please help.